# Access Data Object by ID

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following structs that defined according to the SwiftUI example in Apple.

```
struct Cat: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let audio: [Int]? // list of audio of cat sound
}

struct CatAudio: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let filename: String
}
```

I then would like to access the audio and then deliver in the view.

I have json data like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 55,
    "name": "meow",
    "audio": [6,5]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "meowmeow",
    "audio": [2]
  }
]
```

AudioData.json

```
[
  {
    "id": 5,
    "filename": "5.wav"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "filename": "2.wav"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "filename": "6.wav"
  }
]
```

The json files loaded successfully.

```
@Published var cats: [Cat] = load("CatData.json")
@Published var catAudios: [CatAudio] = load("CatAudio.json")
```

I then tried to get an audio object from my environment model data:

```
@EnvironmentObject var modelData: ModelData
```

and then I want to get an the corresponding audio object of the cat. but I failed to do so as I do not know how to use the "Id" to get it.

Example:

Assume that I got the cat object from my model:

```
 let cat = modelData.cats[0]
```

I then want to get its audio data according to the id stored in the audio list of it

```
let catAudio = modelData.catAudios[cat.audio[0]!] // exception here
```

I found that it is because the array order may not be consistent with the "Id". I want to make use of the "Id" instead of the Array order to get the item.
How can I do it?

========

I have tried to write a function to get the list of CatAudio of a cat.
I have also make audio non-optional.

```
func getAudio(cat: Cat) -> [CatAudio] {
        return cat.audio.compactMap{id in catAudio.filter { $0.id==id } }
}
```

But it complains and said that cannot convert the value of type [CatAudio] to closure result type 'CatAudio'

I got confused with that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use high-order functions to match the id values in the `audio` array with the elements in the CatAudio array

Assuming the 2 arrays and a selected Cat object

```
var cats: [Cat] = ...
var catAudios: [CatAudio] = ...

let cat = cats[0]
```

To select one audio for a one id

```
if let firstId = cat.audio?.first {
    let audio = catAudios.first { $0.id == firstId}
}
```

To get an array of all CatAudio for the `cat` object

```
if let array = cat.audio {
    let values = array.compactMap { id in catAudios.filter { $0.id == id }}
}
```

The code would be simpler if the `audio` array wasn't optional, any reason for it to be declared optional?

Comment: Some of the cat does not have it's voice recorded, that's why optional. Yet, I can change it to an array of size 0, that's fine. How can the code be simpler if that is not optional?!

Comment: Is the above code efficient if I have many cats? Imagine is that an iterator that loop through all the objects in the list and check one by one?

Comment: @user6539552  With a non-optional array you could skip some `if let...` which could make the code shorter and clearer but it's not a must. If you have a lot Cat objects it might be a good idea to turn the CatAudio array into a dictionary with id as key for faster look-up.

Comment: I am new to the development. I only follow the tutorial in Apple, it load the data into a list from Json. Do you mean I should change the code at that point, not using array to hold the Json data? What will be the difference if I use a dict to hold the items?

Comment: i have tried to write a function to get the list of CatAudio object using filter, but seems it does not work.. I have make the CatAudio not optional. (I have edited my question to include the code)

Comment: And what is `catAudio` in that function, a single CatAudio object?